# Check for valid row in tableView Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: mobile, titanium, appcelerator

I have a table view that I am going to populate with data from a contacts picker I then need to get that data back from it when another button is clicked with a while() loop however I can not find anything to give me a truth value for a valid row with db I can use isValidRow() is there something I can use for a tableView?

Comment: what actually is a "valid" tableviewrow? nice appearance? correctly created?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

'

var data = [{title:"Row 1",isvalidRow:"true"}];
var table = Titanium.UI.createTableView({data:data});
win.add(table);
'

you can then get the data which is an array and iterate over the array to see if it's a valid row or no. The valid row will be set when you are reading the data from the contacts DB.

Hope this helps